# Webapp button to duplicate sheet in google sheets

Tags: dom, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I'm trying to create a simple webapp button that it will duplicate sheet in Google sheets , I created the button in HTML and linked it to run the code when its clicked ! but it doesnt seem to work !, can someone tell me what I did wrong ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <base target="_top">
 </head>
  <body>
  <button id="btn">Create</button> 
<script>
  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",doStuff);
  function doStuff(){
    google.script.run.userClicked();
  }
</script>
 </body>
  </html>
```

And here is the code for duplication :

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page');
 }

   function userClicked() {
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet();
     var myValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("M1").getDisplayValue();
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet("Daily Report " + myValue);
   }
```

Comment: In this case when you open the spreadsheet you're opening it on the server and so the active sheet is always the same as ss.getSheets()[0] which is always the left most sheet.  So it would be better to be real precise about which sheet that you wish to open by using getSheetByName().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Duplicating & Deleting Sheets from a WebApp**

Code.gs:

```
function dupSheet(dObj) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(dObj.name));
  ss.duplicateActiveSheet();
  var name="Daily Report " + sh.getRange("A1").getDisplayValue();
  if(!sheetExists(name)) {
    ss.renameActiveSheet("Daily Report " + sh.getRange("A1").getDisplayValue());
  }
  dObj['sA']=getSheetNames().sA;
  return dObj;
}

function getSheetNames() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  var sObj={sA:[]};
  shts.forEach(function(sh){
    sObj.sA.push(sh.getName());
  })
  return sObj;
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dup');
}

function delSheet(dObj) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(dObj.name);
  ss.deleteSheet(sh);
  dObj['sA']=getSheetNames().sA;
  return dObj;
}

function sheetExists(name) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sA=ss.getSheets();
  for(var i=0;i<sA.length;i++) {
    if(name==sA[i].getName()) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

dup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(sObj){
        var select=document.getElementById('sel1');      
        sObj.sA.unshift('Please Select A File Name');
        select.options.length=0;
        for(var i=0;i<sObj.sA.length;i++) {
          select.options[i]=new Option(sObj.sA[i],sObj.sA[i]);
        }
      })
      .getSheetNames();

    });
    function dupSheet() {
      $("#sel1").css('background-color','#ffff00');
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(rObj){
        $('#sel1').css('background-color','#ffffff');
        var select=document.getElementById('sel1');      
        rObj.sA.unshift('Please Select A File Name');
        select.options.length=0;
        for(var i=0;i<rObj.sA.length;i++) {
          select.options[i]=new Option(rObj.sA[i],rObj.sA[i]);
        }
      })
      .dupSheet({name:$('#sel1').val()});
    }
    function delSheet() {
      $("#sel1").css('background-color','#ffff00');
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(rObj){
        $('#sel1').css('background-color','#ffffff');
        var select=document.getElementById('sel1');      
        rObj.sA.unshift('Please Select A File Name');
        select.options.length=0;
        for(var i=0;i<rObj.sA.length;i++) {
          select.options[i]=new Option(rObj.sA[i],rObj.sA[i]);
        }
      })
      .delSheet({name:$('#sel1').val()});
    }
  </script>
  <style>
  input{margin:2px 5px;}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="sel1"></select><label for="sel1">Sheet Name</label>
    <br /><input type="button" value="Duplicate Sheet" onClick="dupSheet();" />
    <br /><input type="button" value="Delete Sheet" onClick="delSheet();" />
  </body>
</html>
```

I used a little JQuery in there too.

Comment: Wow Cooper , this is amazing . Thank you so much , I will be looking through the code and the HTML and try to learn more . Much appreciated all the efforts .

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the SpreadsheetApp [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivesheet).

**getActiveSheet()**

> Gets the active sheet in a spreadsheet. The active sheet in a spreadsheet is the sheet that is being displayed in the spreadsheet UI.

Since you are not using any UI you should instead use other methods of accessing your Sheets and Spreadsheets, such as:

**Obtaining your Spreadsheet**

- [SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)
- [SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl)

**Obtaining your Sheet(s)**

- [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))
- [Spreadsheet.getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and references .